# center stack image and span tag - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to stack the `image`, `first span` and `second span` one after the other for `xs` device. And it should be center aligned for `xs` device.

Here is my piece of code: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qbphtovg/1/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2" style="padding-right:0px">
            <img src="Images/signin_logo.jpg" width="150" height="110" />
            <p> <span style="color:#989898; font-size:36px">Template Fire Sign In</span>
                <br /> <span style="color:#A8A8A8; font-size:18px">Please sign in with your credentials now to get access.</span>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve something like this:  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qbphtovg/1/)

```
      Image
     Span One
  Span Second...
     ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS. It will give you what you are trying to get. But remember, You will get the elements centered for 767px width or less display, which you can change by changing value of max-width.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .row img,
    .row p{
        display:block;
        margin: 10px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```